# How to deal with a server without SSH?

Tags: php, linux, deployment

I'm developing and in a short time will be deploying an app to a server which I have no SSH accesss.

Unfortunately there's just FTP access to deploy this app to the server, which is some kind of LAMP.

Deploying without rsync, scp or git is really cumbersome and prone to errors, not to mention security questions.

What kind of alternative approach can be tried?

PHP scripts?

Comment: Maybe [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) and using https/SSL can help you

Comment: What kind of server are we talking about? Is this a customers own server? What about dependencies (mysql, php extensions, ffmpeg or other junk you need for your project to work?). Is this some dodgy shared hosting?

Comment: It's the customer's production server. Dependencies are simple (mysql, php). It seems to be a shared hosting server.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a shared hosting server, it should have a Cpanel account for the administration of the site.

You can ask your client to create a account with access to the Cpanel, so you can upload and deploy all the files in the server using the file manager maybe ziping all the file and unziping them for deployment.

Comment: are you referring to ftp?

Comment: No. In a shared hosted site, the client ussually have access to a cpanel. From there, the client can add new ftp accounts, access a web based file manager and others tool that can help to deploy the code.

Comment: yup, life without ssh is truly difficult.